# How to set permissions for DooPHP?

Tags: php, security

I have downloaded and installed DooPHP according the [Installation instructions](http://doophp.com/doc/guide/start/install). However, there is no statement on how to set permissions. Also not in `INSTALL.TXT` which comes with the product.

The folder structure reveals a `protected` folder under `app` which contains the config files, which should probably be secured.

By default, the folder and subfolders have `755` and files have `644` permissions. Owner is `root:root`, but I have changed that to `www-data:www-data` to make the Model Generator work.

What would be considered safe permission settings for dooPHP? I'd like to find that out before I go live with it.

I already tried to find advice in the DooPHP forum, but all I found is a [statement about missing security settings](http://doophp.com/oldforum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1172#p6627) from 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in their configuration that prevents somebody browsing into that protected folder.   You could add configuration to the *.htaccess* file to prevent access to it:

```
<Directory /app/protected>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: You would use the `<Directory>` container if placing these rules in the server config. If in `.htaccess`, just place these directives directly in the `/app/protected/.htaccess` file without the `<Directory>` wrapper.